# Execute code before splash screen

Tags: .net, vb.net, startup, splash-screen

I have a VB.NET application with `Enable application framework` checked, and `Splash screen` set. At the same time, I need to run some code before the splash screen is loaded. `MyApplication_Startup` seems to go later, so it's not suitable. I understand it's possible with custom splash screen, but would prefer any other way to make it without more complex customization.

EDIT: Apparently, the issue is different. Code that runs before the splash-screen is thread-specific. It doesn't take proper effect, since splash screen is on another thread.

Answer (score 2):

Under project properties click View Application Events. Then read the comment: ' The following events are available for MyApplication:
    ' 
    ' Startup: Raised when the application starts, before the startup form is created.
    ' Shutdown: Raised after all application forms are closed.  This event is not raised if the application terminates abnormally.
    ' UnhandledException: Raised if the application encounters an unhandled exception.
    ' StartupNextInstance: Raised when launching a single-instance application and the application is already active. 
    ' NetworkAvailabilityChanged: Raised when the network connection is connected or disconnected.

I don't know if oyu have been through this yet.

Comment: For those working in C#, these events are in WindowsFormsApplicationBase.

Answer (score 1):

Have you stepped through your code using the F8 key?  The debugger can show you where you can add code before your splash screen is shown.